# Best way to represent policy-population data in Postgres

Tags: django, database, postgresql

I want to build a Django service where user can define some policy to some population.

Policy sample:

```
default policy:
{
"field1":{
        "rule1":"somerule",
        "rule2":"somerule",
        "rule3":"somerule"
},
"filed2":{
    "rule1":"somerule",
    "rule2":"somerule",
    "moredata":[
        {"one":1,"two":2,"three":3},
        {"one":1,"two":2,"three":3}]
},
"filed3":{}
}
```

Population sample:

```
default population:
{
"field1":[{"1":"some1"},
        {"2":"some2"},
        {"3":"some3"}],
"filed2":[{"1":"some1"},
        {"2":"some2"},
        {"3":"some3"}],
"filed3":[{"1":"some1"},
        {"2":"some2"},
        {"3":"some3"}]
}
```

I want to find the best way to represent that data in PostgresDB, I thought about two db relations:

1:

```
population to policy:           field to population:

population  policyId            field   value           population
pop1        56                  field2  (lat,lon,rad)   pop1
pop2        999                 field3  (lat,lon,rad)   pop2
pop3        3                   field4  456             pop3
```

2:

```
population to policy:           expression to population:

population  policyId            expression                         population
pop1        56                  "filed1 AND filed4 OR filed2"      pop1
pop2        999                 "filed1 OR filed4 "                pop2
pop3        3
```

What is better, and is there any better ways to represent data of this kind?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good fit for [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield).